# Best options to pull data from SaaS API to Synapse

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

What are the best options for ingesting data from SaaS Application to Synapse through API with Authentication? We have a couple of SaaS Applications such as NetSuite, EyeShare & SAP SaaS Applications, and planning to ingest the data to Synapse but not finding enough information on the connectors supported by Synapse or ADF. Kindly help to suggest the tool or the method to get the SaaS data via. APIs.

Comment: Use pipelines which is Azure Data Factory (ADF) under the hood.  The Web and Web Hook tasks are compatible with calling REST APIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As wBob said, I think we can use [Web Hook tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/data-factory/control-flow-webhook-activity) in pipelines to call API and ingest the data to Synapse.